# Improving poor intermittent SQL query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have a moderately complex nested T-SQL query, which for the most part has good performance, except at the start of each of my 2-week pay periods (where there are fewer records to process!) the query bogs down orders of magnitude slower.  Then at some point in the bi-weekly period, SQL Server (2008) determines the execution plan should change and everything is back to normal speeds.  I have the execution plans for the "good" and "bad" scenarios, but I am a n00b in this area and I do not know how to interpret them. What is the next step for me here?  Post the query? The execution plans?  Read some articles/book?

Comment: Do you have *actual* execution plans, derived from running the queries directly? Or did you pull the plans from the plan cache, or just generate *estimated* plans?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Actual.

Comment: Great, you can upload them to [answers.sqlperformance.com](http://answers.sqlperformance.com/). You might also consider using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the query - I suspect that when the data is small you are still using a plan that is optimal for large data sets but not for small ones. Forcing a recompile every time takes a hit on compile but it prevents this scenario.

Comment: Also for interpreting query plans you should consider using our free tool [Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/) and reading Grant Fritchey's free eBook, [SQL Server Execution Plans](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/65831/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am being hit with the extra slow time again now, and using `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` did not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help over at answers.sqlperformance.com, and while `UPDATE STATISTICS <table>` does help, it appears to be masking the real problem. I was using the constructs `(SELECT COUNT(*) ...) = 0` and `(SELECT * ...) IS NULL` when I should have been using `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * ...)`. Changing these resulted in almost another order of magnitude improvement in all cases. It looks like the SQL Plan Optimizer is able to work much better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating statistics on the tables in the query at the start of the 2 week period:

DBCC UPDATE STATISTICS table-name

there are some options, like WITH FULLSCAN you could experiment with as well. Take a look in the SQL Server docs.

Comment: I am having the extreme slowdown problems today. I tried the `UPDATE STATISTICS <tablename>` and the query time immediately resumed reasonable execution times (~1 sec).  I will keep an eye on this but I think this fixes things.